# Add a node and connect with every other node using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to add a single node and connect it with every other node in a given graph with `n` nodes.

I am sharing an MWE below.

```
library(igraph)
g <- sample_k_regular(10, 3)
g <- g + vertices(11)
```

How can I connect node 11 with every other node in an efficient way? Also, when I add node 11 and plot the graph, for some reason, the node numbering is lost. I'd like to preserve the node numbering while adding the node.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
g <- g %>%
  add_vertices(1) %>%
  add_edges(c(rbind(seq(vcount(.) - 1), 11)))
```

[image]

## Data

```
set.seed(1)
g <- sample_k_regular(10, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: I am following your steps however it does not produce the desired output.  Here is what I am doing: ```set.seed(1);
 g <- sample_k_regular(10, 3);
g %>%
     add_vertices(1) %>%
     add_edges(c(rbind(seq(vcount(.) - 1), 11)));```

Comment: In fact, when I call ```gorder(g)```, I realize that the number of nodes does not change after calling ```add_vertices``` method.

Comment: @whitepanda You should use `g <- `  in front of my code. See my update